# Hibernate 5 password encryption in cnf file

Tags: java, hibernate, password-encryption

I have Java app that has remote db credentials in hibernate config file in JAR file. I want to encrypt password that if "simple" user would search for the password in would be not human readable.
I have seen Jasypt examples on the web, but there is Jasypt only for hibernate 4. There is no for hubernate 5.
Can I use Jasypt for hibernate 4 with hibernate 5?
Or maybe there is another solution? I know that placing login and password in JAR file is not safe, but thats the way my app is created.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: serialize the passwords file ...

Answer (score 0):

Place the password(s) in an external `.properties` file. To use the application in test-setup, you can place a properties file inside your project with fake/test credentials to a local database. For production you can place the secrets on the specific machine that needs to connect to the database.

Never put things you want to keep secret in the jar, source or repository.

Comment: I know it is not safe to keep secret in jar, but it has to be done.

Comment: If you accept to have it in de .jar, then just put it in plain-text. Any obfuscation you do can be easily undone.

Where is the jar running? On a platform controlled by yourself (or anyone else who wants the secret to be safe), or at other machines? Basically: you should make it so that the user of the jar does not want the secret to come out; otherwise it is inevitable.